# Java Parsefloat Exception with a string that is number followed by characters

Tags: java, numberformatexception, parsefloat

When I run this line of code: Float.parseFloat("1460000 JPY") I get the error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1460000 JPY"

This string is coming from an API call from a form where this is a text field with no validation. It usually works because people put in just a number, but sometimes you get this issue. How do I get it to return just the initial numbers as a float and disregard the trailing alpha characters?

Comment: You need to strip out the letters first, then parse what's left to a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** to account for the bug that @Tom brought up:

```
Float.parseFloat("1.46 JPY".replaceAll("[^0-9.]",""));
```

> `1.46`

the above is a superior solution. See below for explanation.

As @azurefrog said, stripping out non-numeric characters and then parsing what is left as a `Float` is the way to go.You can accomplish this using the following code:

```
Float.parseFloat("1460000 JPY".replaceAll("[^0-9]",""));
```

> `1460000.0`

This is not very robust though, because for inputs like `"1.46"` the output becomes

> `146.0`

`.replaceAll("[^0-9.]","")` fixes this inaccuracy by adding the decimal `.` character to the exclusion regex like so `[^0-9.]`

Comment: Stripping the decimal separator is not really clever.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. Are you saying that `Float.parseFloat("1460000.0".replaceAll("[^0-9]",""));` would result in `14600000.0`?

Comment: I would avoid using `.` as a fix value since the delimiter differs on different locales.

Comment: In addition to the locale issue, you would again fail if you tried to parse a string such as "1.2.3" - you would need a more complex regex expression to insure there was AT MOST one decimal point (and that is putting aside the locale issue for the moment.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex to find if that string contains only digit or not

```
String apistring = "1460000 JPY";
if(apistring.matches("[0-9]+")){
// do your code
}else{
// throw some  error message
}
```

Stripping char from that will be difficult as you said its a input field and  user can enter any text. You can strip it off only if you know that there is a particular pattern

Answer (score 3):

Since [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is very lenient about parsing Strings I would recommend that.

You can use it like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
try {
    float parsedValue = df.parse("1460000 JPY").floatValue();
    System.out.println(parsedValue);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
    // handle exception a bit more
}
```

This prints:

> 1460000.0

As you can see the [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method can throw a `ParseException` if the passed String starts with something else than a number, like:

> blub 1460000 JPY

If that won't happen in your app, then you don't have to bother about it.

Comment: using `Float.parseFloat("1460000 JPY".replaceAll("[^0-9]",""));` handles preceding characters as well.

Comment: And it does some bad things with values containing a decimal separator, so how about "no"? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex to extract the numbers in input .

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

and then parse float from it. Only downside is that it will extract all numbers (It will  extract 1245 and 3 both from 1245 JPY 3).